# SharePoint-hosted Task pane app not authenticating

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365, office-app

Summary:
I have an Office 365 E3 account where I'm trying to deploy a Word task pane app that will read some SharePoint list data. Right now, I'm just trying to get the task pane app to load, however, it shows the Office 365 login page (in the pane) but does not do anything after clicking Login.

Details:
I went through the instructions provided here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179815.aspx

Basically, I create an App for SharePoint configured as SharePoint-hosted, then in the same project, added an App for Office (Task Pane App for Word only). The SharePoint app also has a custom document library.

I am able to install the app to my App Catalog, and it correctly shows up in Site Contents where I see it being provisioned to the app web. I can also launch Word 2013 with the Trusted App Catalog configured correctly, and I am able to see my Task Pane App and insert it. When I click Insert, it loads it but prompts for credentials.
I am using the same credentials all throughout this exercise so by virtue of being able to install and deploy the SharePoint app, you can trust that I'm providing the right credentials.

It also appears the custom document library is never created - I wonder if both suffer from the same underlying issue.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem and the solution provided in the answer below did not help.

After some desparation i created a taskpane app using the Napa Cloud App, opened the application in Visual Studio and went looking for differences.

In the Taskpane app manifest.xml file i found the following entries which were missing in my own application manifest:

```
<AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://login.microsoftonline-int.com</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://login.microsoftonline.com</AppDomain>
</AppDomains>
```

This solved my problem and cured one horrible friday.

Comment: This worked for me too! Strange that this isn't documented somewhere on MSDN. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work. It turns out doing a Deploy from Visual Studio (whether you right-clicked Deploy or F5-debug), the installation of the app isn't enough.

To make it work, I skipped doing a Deploy all together, but instead published my app. I then took the .app file and loaded it in my App Packages folder, and then deployed it from there.

Unfortunately, I don't know the difference between the two, but I'm assuming it has something to do with provisioning the app web for the Office App.